# vb split string in to paragraph size chuncks

Tags: vb.net, sorting, split

i have data form machines that test equipment that comes to me in txt files like this.

> STANDARDIZE REPORT  TIME = 1550 9/22/14
>  REEL SCAN  CLAY
>                         CHAN 1    CHAN 2    CHAN 3    CHAN 4    CHAN 5    CHAN 6
>  AIR COUNTS (CCHi):     75455.    74464.    75353.    75539.
>   75300.    73303.
>  FLAG COUNTS (C2CHi):   75463.    74462.    75340.    75537.    75287.    73283.
>  COUNTS/T0 (TCHi):      1.0061    0.9929    1.0047    1.0072    1.0040    0.9774
>  RS RATIOS (RS2):                 1.0133    1.0014    0.9989    1.0021    1.0294
>  FLAG RATIOS (RFS2):              1.0001    1.0003    1.0001    1.0003    1.0004
>  FLAG RAT/T0 (FSTR2):             1.0001    1.0003    1.0001    1.0003
>   1.0004
>
> STANDARDIZE REPORT  TIME = 1550 9/22/14
>  1ST COAT   BASIS WT
>   F/A RATIO        0.7582  NET AIR CNTS    73044.5  NET FLAG CNTS
>   55379.7  BKGROUND CNTS     484.0 BW OF FLAG       50.196  DFRAC            0.1006  ZFRAC            0.0000
>  UP AIR TEMP        0.00  LO AIR TEMP        0.00  SOURCE TEMP        0.00  RCVR TEMP          0.00 UP
>   HEAD TEMP    2616.71  LO HEAD TEMP     415.47
>
> STANDARDIZE REPORT  TIME = 1550 9/22/14
>  1ST COAT   MOISTURE
>  
>   TRANSMISSION IR
>  Gain:  0
>  GAIN FCTR        1.0000  STDR
>   1.0000  RS               0.9907
>  RFS              1.0000  RFS0             1.0000  RS0              1.0000
>  REF             75836.3  MES             76550.6
>  REFRAT           1.0112  MESRAT           1.0207
>
> STANDARDIZE REPORT  TIME = 1550 9/22/14
>  1ST COAT   CLAY
>                         CHAN 1    CHAN 2    CHAN 3    CHAN 4    CHAN 5    CHAN 6
>  AIR COUNTS (CCHi):     75836.    76551.    75018.    69494.
>   74184.    72229.
>  FLAG COUNTS (C2CHi):   75811.    76521.    75001.    69469.    74135.    72195.
>  COUNTS/T0 (TCHi):      1.0112    1.0207    1.0002    0.9266    0.9891    0.9631
>  RS RATIOS (RS2):                 0.9907    1.0109    1.0913    1.0223    1.0499
>  FLAG RATIOS (RFS2):              1.0000    0.9999    1.0000    1.0003    1.0001
>  FLAG RAT/T0 (FSTR2):             1.0000    0.9999    1.0000    1.0003
>   1.0001
>
> BACKGROUND REPORT   TIME = 1551 9/22/14
>  RAW STOCK  BASIS WT
>   BKG COUNTS        333.0
>
> BACKGROUND REPORT   TIME = 1551 9/22/14
>  RAW STOCK  MOISTURE
>  
>   TRANSMISSION IR
>  DARK CNTS REF      461.  PHSE 2 REF        3528. 
>   PHSE 3 REF       10326.  PHSE 4 REF       34457.
>  DARK CNTS MES
>   474.  PHSE 2 MES        3532.  PHSE 3 MES       10338.  PHSE 4 MES       34499.
>  GAF1             1.0000  GAF2             1.0001

i want to be able to split the string by the double line-breaks and then sort the test by machine name on the second line of each data chunk.

so it would output only the test by the REEL SCAN  CLAY, or 1ST COAT BASIS WT depending on what test you want.
Output may look like this.

> STANDARDIZE REPORT  TIME = 1510 9/22/14
>  REEL SCAN  CLAY
>                         CHAN 1    CHAN 2    CHAN 3    CHAN 4    CHAN 5    CHAN 6
>  AIR COUNTS (CCHi):     75455.    74464.    75353.    75539.
>   75300.    73303.
>  FLAG COUNTS (C2CHi):   75463.    74462.    75340.    75537.    75287.    73283.
>  COUNTS/T0 (TCHi):      1.0061    0.9929    1.0047    1.0072    1.0040    0.9774
>  RS RATIOS (RS2):                 1.0133    1.0014    0.9989    1.0021    1.0294
>  FLAG RATIOS (RFS2):              1.0001    1.0003    1.0001    1.0003    1.0004
>  FLAG RAT/T0 (FSTR2):             1.0001    1.0003    1.0001    1.0003
>   1.0004
>
> STANDARDIZE REPORT  TIME = 1525 9/22/14
>  REEL SCAN  CLAY
>                         CHAN 1    CHAN 2    CHAN 3    CHAN 4    CHAN 5    CHAN 6
>  AIR COUNTS (CCHi):     72581.    73115.    75020.    75437.
>   74880.    72770.
>  FLAG COUNTS (C2CHi):   72606.    73125.    75037.    75463.    74897.    72798.
>  COUNTS/T0 (TCHi):      0.9677    0.9749    1.0003    1.0058    0.9984    0.9703
>  RS RATIOS (RS2):                 0.9927    0.9675    0.9621    0.9693    0.9974
>  FLAG RATIOS (RFS2):              1.0002    1.0001    1.0000    1.0001    1.0000
>  FLAG RAT/T0 (FSTR2):             1.0002    1.0001    1.0000    1.0001
>   1.0000
>
> STANDARDIZE REPORT  TIME = 1540 9/22/14
>  REEL SCAN  CLAY
>                         CHAN 1    CHAN 2    CHAN 3    CHAN 4    CHAN 5    CHAN 6
>  AIR COUNTS (CCHi):     72386.    73145.    75112.    75481.
>   74953.    72838.
>  FLAG COUNTS (C2CHi):   72462.    73174.    75132.    75498.    74976.    72846.
>  COUNTS/T0 (TCHi):      0.9652    0.9753    1.0015    1.0064    0.9994    0.9712
>  RS RATIOS (RS2):                 0.9896    0.9637    0.9590    0.9658    0.9938
>  FLAG RATIOS (RFS2):              1.0007    1.0008    1.0008    1.0007    1.0009
>  FLAG RAT/T0 (FSTR2):             1.0007    1.0008    1.0008    1.0007
>   1.0009

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a code translation service

Comment: your question is unclear. show the desired output. when does one machine end and other start?

Comment: @MattWilko - sorry was not trying to get a translation, just trying to give as much info as possible.

Comment: @MihaiC - each machine test is separated by the blank line, so the start of each test has a time stamp in the first line. The txt document will full of the test, i simply i want separate each test into an array i guess, so i can then out a text document with only the "1ST COAT CLAY" or "REEL CLAY"

Comment: There's a number of ways of going about this, from using regular expressions to parsing it using a `StringReader` into sections yourself.  I would go and investigate what will work for you, then if you have a specific question about some code you've tried, that's when Stack Overflow can help you.

Comment: at least attempt a solution, I can't bring myself to write it all for you, `File.ReadLines` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx, will probably be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give in, you want to break some lines into a

```
Class Paragraph
    Inherits List(Of String)

    Public Property Line2 As String
        If Me.Count >= 2 Then
            Return Me(1)
        End If

        Return Null
    End Property
End Class
```

to do this, you'll want code something like,

```
Public Function FileBreaker(
    path As String) As IEnumerable(Of Paragraph)

    Dim emptyLine = False
    Dim nextParagraph = New Paragraph()
    For Each Dim line In File.ReadLines(path)
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(line) Then
            If emptyLine Then
                emptyLine = False
                Yield nextParagraph
                nextParagraph = New Paragraph()
            Else
                emptyLine = True
            End If

            Continue
        End If

        If emptyLine Then
            nextParagraph.Add(String.Empty)
            emptyLine = False
        End If

        nextParagraph.Add(line)
    Next
End Function
```

Which you can use to do something like,

```
Dim sortedParagraphs = FileBreaker("MyData.txt").OrderBy(Function(p) p.Line2)
```

Comment: Thanks @jodrell, that got me going

Answer (score 2):

**Updated** code to match desired output

### NOTE: the code is in java since the initial tag was `Java`

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("machines.txt"));
    final String search="REEL SCAN CLAY";

    String allMachines = "";
    //read line by line, adding each line to a string delimited by ";" ignore empty line
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        if (!line.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            allMachines = allMachines + line + ";"; //machine attribute delimiter
        } else {
            allMachines = allMachines + line + "%"; //machine delimiter
        }
    }
    scanner.close();

    allMachines = allMachines.replace(";%", "%"); //no need for that extra ; and the end of a machine
    final String[] machines = allMachines.split("%"); // identify all machines

    for (final String machine : machines) {
        final String[] machineAttributes = machine.split(";"); //split via the attribute delimiter
        //extract attributes for each machine
        //the one you want is the second so [1]
        final String searchKey= machineAttributes[1];
        if(searchKey.equalsIgnoreCase(search)){
              //this machine contains the test you want. write all of it's attributes
              //to another file or outputstream
              for(int i=0;i<machineAttributes.length;i++){
                //write machineAttributes[i] to a file, one on each line
              }                  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This appears to be Java, not even c#...

Comment: this is java isnt it?
need it in vb.net.

Comment: @JamesThorpe wait why did this appear in the java section? my bad, op must have changed the tags or i'm just blind... anyway, Op just translate the code to vb..

Comment: @MihaiC yeah you're right - looking back, it was originally tagged with both Java and VB.Net

Comment: There is no `Scanner` class in .Net, so you'd need to identify something equivalent to start with

Comment: At first I thought this was a troll to a "Give me codez!" type request... "Sure you can have codez, here's some Java ;)"

Comment: Sorry guys, i did edit the post after i was warned about asking for conversion of code, and took the java part out